# Learning Python extracting data from a website

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a script to get data from an internal website that exports to Excel, that data gets broken into smaller pieces and gets emailed to technicians. (metric data) I am trying to get into the website using robobrowser but I keep getting this:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Aging.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Aging.py", line 3, in 
    from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\robobrowser-0.5.3-py3.6.egg\robobrowser__init__.py", line 3, in 
    from .browser import RoboBrowser

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\robobrowser-0.5.3-py3.6.egg\robobrowser\browser.py", line 7, in 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4__init__.py", line 30, in 
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder__init__.py", line 308, in 
    from . import _htmlparser

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder_htmlparser.py", line 7, in 
    from html.parser import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'

Here is the code:

```
import webbrowser
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

#Set BR module
br = RoboBrowser()

#open a website
br.open("https://www.whatever.com")

form = br.get_form()
form ['username'] = "username"
form ['password'] = "password"
br.submit_form(form)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure, if RoboBrowser comes with it, but I would assume that you need to install the package [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should try reinstalling RoboBrowser and BeautifulSoup. What's happening is that when you `import robobrowser`, RoboBrowser then tries to `import BeautifulSoup` (a python module) which then tries to `import _htmlparser` (a python module that is part of the BeautifulSoup package), but it can't find that file and the load fails.

This is most likely caused by a missing or corrupted file (or maybe an out of date version). If you reinstall `BeautifulSoup` (and probably `robobrowser` to be safe) it should fix the problem.